# How to force user to enter input value in specific format?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a form where I want user should enter border css code in specific format.

e.g.

```
<input type="text" name="border_css" id="border_css" class="form-control"> <!-- Expecting this should be readonly -->
```

input value should be in format = "Npx solid #color"

like `1px dotted #FF0000` / `2px groove rgba(0,0,0,0.8)`

Is there any javascript / any other option with 2 dropdowns for `border-width` and `border-style` and `select color input field` which will give output in `border-width border-style border-color` and put value in readonly input ? (in my example, autofill this value in input with name `border_css` while keeping it as readonly)

box-shadow generator is available in this format which I used for box-shadow  input field.... (https://codepen.io/Montego/pen/oJgtl). But I googled for helpful border generator without any success.

Comment: The best way to use regular expressions.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```js
const width = document.querySelector('input[type="range"]');
const style = document.querySelector('select');
const color = document.querySelector('input[type="color"]');
const result = document.getElementById("border_css");

function updateInput() {
  result.value = width.value + "px " + style.value + " " + color.value;
}
width.addEventListener('input', updateInput);
style.addEventListener('input', updateInput);
color.addEventListener('input', updateInput);
```

```css
td, th{
  text-align:start;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Width</th>
    <th>Style</th>
    <th>Color</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="range" min="1" max="100"></td>
    <td>
      <select>
        <option value="dotted">dotted</option>
        <option value="dashed">dashed</option>
        <option value="solid">solid</option>
        <option value="double">double</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td><input type="color"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<input type="text" name="border_css" id="border_css" class="form-control" placeholder="result">
```

Comment: thanx...will try your solution and let you know... I will need to play with my form code as it is containing about 80 input fields... so give me some time for testing... but Thank you very much.. I think your answer will be answer to my issue.

Comment: @DrManishLataa-ManoharJoshi No problem. Let me know if you come across any issues or need any help :)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, the following will help for hex and just add pattern for rgb…

```html
<input type="text" name="border_css" id="border_css" class="form-control" onkeyup="a('...')" pattern=\"[a-fA-F0-9]+\">
```

Just add width validation using the same pattern method… also add value…

If I can help please let me know.